# Reading in file using C++

Tags: c++, file-io

this is a problem from google code jam in 2008
https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32016/dashboard

the statement of the problem is reproduced:

You are given two vectors v1=(x1,x2,...,xn) and v2=(y1,y2,...,yn). The scalar product of these vectors is a single number, calculated as x1y1+x2y2+...+xnyn.

Suppose you are allowed to permute the coordinates of each vector as you wish. Choose two permutations such that the scalar product of your two new vectors is the smallest possible, and output that minimum scalar product.

Input

The first line of the input file contains integer number T - the number of test cases. For each test case, the first line contains integer number n. The next two lines contain n integers each, giving the coordinates of v1 and v2 respectively.

Output

For each test case, output a line

Case #X: Y
where X is the test case number, starting from 1, and Y is the minimum scalar product of all permutations of the two given vectors.

and I copied and pasted Bohua's solutions, and attached

```
ifstream in ("A-small-practice.in");        
ofstream out("A-small-practice.out");
```

and the result was the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream in ("A-small-practice.in");        
ofstream out("A-small-practice.out");
int numCase;
cin >> numCase;
int i, j, n;
long long c;
for (i = 0; i < numCase; i++)
{
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long> array1, array2;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cin >> c;
        array1.push_back(c);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cin >> c;
        array2.push_back(c);
    }
    sort(array1.begin(), array1.end());
    sort(array2.begin(), array2.end(), greater<long long>());
    long long ans = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        ans += (array1[j] * array2[j]);
    cout << "Case #" << (i+1) << ": " << ans << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

However, it didn't produce the output I wanted. A-small-practice.out was just blank. 
Is there something wrong with the way I inserted

```
ifstream in ("A-small-practice.in");        
ofstream out("A-small-practice.out");
```

I wanted C++ to read the A-small-practice.in file and produce A-small-practice.out file, and the code must be correct because all I did was copy & pasted Bohua's solutions except for adding the above two lines.

I just wanted to learn how to load .in extension file into c++, and produce the 
desired output.

PS. I got it

Comment: You dont ever write to file. `cin` and `cout` read and write to the command line or terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You dont ever write to the file, named "A-small-practice.out". cin and cout write and read from the command line or terminal.

You opened 2 files using ifstream and ofstream. You refer to these objects in your code using the names `in` and `out`.

Try doing something like `out << "Send text to file" << endl;` Since `out` is an `ofstream` type you can output data to it. This is done using the stream insertion operator: `<<`

For example, you probably want to do something like `out << "Case #" << (i+1) << ": " << ans << endl;`, possibly. (I'm not sure exactly what your program is supposed do to as there are no comments or explanations.)

Comment: sorry, I revised the question.

Comment: @user98235 Did my answer solve the problem? I can't tell if your algorithm didn't work or whether the output didn't work?

Comment: I just wanted the program to extract numbers from A-small-practice.in file and produce the correct output in A-small-practice.out file.

Comment: algorithm must work for sure because I copied & pasted the solution. It's not my algorithm. It's just that the program isn't reading the input. The output always comes out blank.

Comment: The solution that you copied was probably run in a script or framework that redirected stdin and stdout.  You want to read and write directly to a file. Re-read the answer that Edward Bird gave you.

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming, so I don't think I'm at the level to understand his answer. (not quite sure what Try doing something like out << "Send text to file" << endl; Since out is an ofstream type you can output data to it. This is done using the stream insertion operator: <<  means). Does it read .in file and output the desired output or something? I probably just should've asked simple examples. All I wanted to know was not how the algorithm works, but how C++ reads and outputs files.

Comment: What it means is copy the line from his answer and paste it into your code and try it.

Comment: @user98235 Yeah, sorry I didn't realize that you didn't already know C++. My suggestion would be try and learn some C from the web. Try cplusplus.com 's tutorial.

Comment: @Edward Bird Thanks. I will do so

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line `cin >> numCase;`, try this:

```
in >> numCase;
out << "Number of cases = " << numCase << std::endl;
```

This should at least print *something* to A-small-practice.out. If it prints `Number of cases = 0` then we know something is wrong with your input (that is, at the very least the input file does not contain the same data in the same way your input logic is trying to read).

Once you have determined the value to which the input logic sets `numCase`, you can
delete the line that prints `"Number of cases = "` (since it isn't part of the desired output of your program).

If you see something other than just `0` on that line of output, then we can look at what's inside the loop. But since you see nothing at all right now, it's worth checking to see if the program is actually doing anything at all. If the input logic sets `numCase = 0` then the rest of the program is designed not to print anything.